# Add filter on left outer join in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, addition, outer-join

I Have a scenario where there are 3 tables, First table have id, name. Second table have id, status, Third table have id, dept_id.

First table is the parent table and have superset of data. Second table doesn’t have all the records while third have all of the records as First table.
[Table A,Table B, Table C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h89pJ.png)

My query is to retrieve ids based on dept_id. If I pass status then only ids tagged to that dept and status should be displayed else if I don’t pass status or if I pass null then all ids tagged to input dept_id should be displayed.

Here inputs are dept_id and status(not mandatory)

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h89pJ.png)

Expected output:
I am passing deptid = 'A' and if I pass status = 'new' then only 1,2 has to be displayed and if I don't pass status then all 1,2,3,4 have to be displayed.
I am trying to insert the output into gt table twice by using if status is not null else pass status. I don’t want to write 2 inserts and try to optimize my code here.

```
If status is not null then
Insert into gt_temp
Select a.id from a,b,c
Where a.id=b.id(+)
And a.id=c.id
And c.dept_id= ‘A’
And b.status= ‘new’;
Else
Insert into gt_temp
Select a.id from a,b,c
Where a.id=b.id(+)
And a.id=c.id
And c.dept_id= ‘A’;

End if;
```

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Click on 'edit'. [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you're passing `dept_id` and `status` as parameters. Then you'd outer join `b` and `c` to `a` on `id` (as it is the only common column).

As `dept_id` is obligatory, use it "as is"; `status` can (but doesn't have to) be passed to query so - indicate that in `where` clause.

Something like this:

```
insert into gt_temp
  select a.id
  from a left join b on a.id = b.id
         left join c on c.id = a.id
  where c.dept_id = :par_dept_id
    and (b.status = :par_status or :par_status is null)
```

Comment: Thank you, I would say a and c have same number of records and we don’t need left join in c

Comment: You're welcome. That's not what you said ("while third have most of the records"). "Most of the records" isn't exactly the "same number of records". At least, that's how I understood it.